# Warning: sqlsrv_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db.inc.php on line 27

Tags: sql-server, objetos, php-7

Estou com o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: sqlsrv_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db.inc.php on line 27
```

Já procurei em alguns fóruns, mas não encontrei nada que resolvesse.

Estou usando PHP 7.3

Código abaixo:

```
<?php

class MsSqlDb{
    private $host;
    private $connectionInfo;
    private $conn;

    /** @description construtor default function __construct($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco) */
    public function __construct($host='XX.XX.XX.XX', $usuario='XX', $senha='XX', $banco='XX'){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->connectionInfo = array('Database'=>$banco, 'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8', 'UID'=>$usuario, 'PWD'=>$senha);
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->host, $this->connectionInfo);

        if(!$this->conn){  //nao foi possivel estabelecer a conexao
            echo "Erro ao estabelecer conexao com o Banco de Dados.\n"; 
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }   
    }
    
    /** @description destrutor default da classe*/  
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->close($this);
    }

    /** @description close() fecha conexao com o banco */
    public function close(){
        sqlsrv_close ($this);
    }

    /** @description query() retorna um resource que deve ser passadi a funcao fetch_array */
    public function query($sql){
        return sqlsrv_query($this->conn,$sql,array(),array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
    }

    /** @description fecth_array() retorna um vetor contendo os campos como indice*/
    public function fetch_array($rs){
        return sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        //return sqlsrv_free_stmt($rs , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /** @description affected_rows() retorna o numero de linhas afetadas pela consulta */
    public function affected_rows($rs){
        return sqlsrv_rows_affected($rs);
    }
    
    /** @description num_rows() retorna o número de linhas em um conjunto de resultados. */
    public function num_rows($rs){
        return sqlsrv_num_rows($rs);
    }
    
    public function commit(){
        sqlsrv_commit($this->conn); 
    }

    public function escape($str){
        // procurar biblioteca PDO
    }

    function getBanco(){
        return $this->banco;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dentro da sua função `close`, você está passando o parâmetro `$this`, que se refere ao objeto da classe MsSqlDb, no entanto o método `sqlsrv_close` requer que o seu parâmetro seja do tipo resource. Como o propósito é fechar a conexão, o correto seria passar a conexão como parâmetro, no seu caso o atributo `$this->conn`.

**Solução:**

```
public function close(){
    sqlsrv_close ($this->conn);
}
```

Comment: Valeu Vitor. Resolvido.